# Dynamic border widths with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like my borders to scale dynamically, so that they're always the same relative width.

Here, the green border is static, no matter how much you change the window:
http://jsfiddle.net/bucR3/

Sadly. simply adding the rule

```
border: 4% solid green
```

doesn't allow for dynamic borders, as shown here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bucR3/1/

(It's not even valid)

How can I make adaptive borders that are always the same size relatively? Is there a jquery way, that can target < IE 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to add some extra markup to your page, you can go for a CSS solution:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"><div>I am a box</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    color: white;
    padding: 4%;
    background: green;
}

.box > div {
    background: red;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bucR3/4/)**

Comment: This is a eloquent solution. Not a border but will visually appear to be one.

Answer (score 0):

You can express the border-width as a function of the innerWidth of the window like this...

```
$(window).resize(function (){
    $(".box").css({"border-width": window.innerWidth/100 * 4});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use em's but this means that you have to be a bit more explicit about your font-size declarations. See an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bucR3/3/

```
$(window)
    .on('resize', function() {
        $(document.body).css('font-size', Math.min(document.body.clientWidth / 1080, 1) * 10);
    })
    .trigger('resize');
```

Basically, the body has a base font size of 10px which you overwrite on resize. And then the border is some multiple of the base font size. But then the content has to have it's font-size reset. If you apply a font size directly to the element with the border this will break.